# Configure Filebeat to not delete AWS SQS message if the message does not match the file_selectors

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, filebeat, elk

**Scenario**:

AWS S3 is configured to send event notification to SQS queue

Filebeat is using `aws-s3-plugin` to pull logs from S3 through the SQS queue

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: aws-s3
    queue_url: https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aws-id/queue-name
    gzip: true
    file_selectors:
      - regex: '.*-mytype.log.*'
```

Filebeat deletes all the messages present in the queue, whereas it should only process and delete the messages matching the `file_selectors` regex

> Question: How to configure `filebeat` to **not** delete SQS queue message
> if the message does not match the `file_selectors` regex?

P.S.

The use case that I am trying to achieve is

1. AWS S3 notification -> SQS queue(all type of files)
2. Multiple filebeat instances configured with the same queue

   - Filebeat-1: configured `file_selectors` for file_type_1. filebeat output: Logstash
   - Filebeat-2: configured `file_selectors` for file_type_2. filebeat output: Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

@sniper I do not think the configuration would work in the manner you want it to using a single SQS queue. Each filebeat input will try to read all messages from the queue and use `file_selectors` to decide which files to download but read and ignore all other messages.

A pattern that you can use is fanout using SNS and SQS. S3 publishes events to SNS when a file is uploaded. Multiple SQS queues each corresponding to a filebeat input is subscribed to the SNS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html

Comment: The original intention was to fan out using SNS. But SNS supports only prefix/suffix type to determine under which SQS queue the message should go to. In case my it is based on the log file name and just prefix/suffix is not enough

Comment: Okay, in that case you can explore having a Lambda function subscribe to the SNS and forwarding the message to the correct SQS queue. Obviously this is another moving piece in the solution and additional cost for lambda. Is this something you might consider ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Lamda could have been used to forward message to multiple SQS queues.
What I ended up doing was have a filebeat in between that pushes onto different kafka topics based on log file name